# Percentage padding/width off in safari

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to create a fluid grid layout with different columns. I have one wrapper with 2 50% columns and one wrapper with 4 25% columns. This is working well in all browsers exept safari there is a tiny gab (1 pixel?) after the last column. After adding margin and padding its getting worse, the gab is much bigger and different width when resizing the browser.

I can't find what is causing this behaviour, what am I doing wrong here??

The HTML:

```
    <div id="column2">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="column4">
    <div class="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box4">box4</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>               
</div>
```

CSS (I left out the reset css it's included in the fiddle):

```
    #column2 {
width:84%;
height:auto;
padding-left:8%;
padding-right:8%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#FFFFCC;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:50%;
height:100px;
background-color:#FFFF66
}

.right {
float:left;
width:50%;
height:100px;
background-color:#FF9900;
}



#column4 {
width:84%;
height:auto;
padding-left:8%;
padding-right:8%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#66FFFF;
}

#column4 .box1, #column4 .box2, #column4 .box3, #column4 .box4{
float:left;
width:22.25%;
height:100px;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
margin-left:1%;
}

#column4 .box1 {
background-color: #FF3300;
margin-left:0;
}

.box2 {
background-color: #333399;
}

.box3 {
background-color: #3366FF;
}

.box4 {
background-color: #009900;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

I've setup a quick basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/emmetje/7ttsE/2/

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

its not working 100%

but this better : http://jsfiddle.net/7ttsE/4/

```
<div id="column2">
<div id="spaces">%8</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div id="spaces">%8</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="column4">
<div id="spaces">%8</div>
<div class="box1">box1</div>
<div id="margin">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box2">box2</div>
<div id="margin">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box3">box3</div>
<div id="margin">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box4">box4</div>
<div id="spaces">%8</div>
<div class="clear"></div>               
</div>



html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}


#spaces {
    width:8%;
    float:left;
}
#margin {
 float:left;
    width:1%;
}
#column2 {
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#FFFFCC;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:42%;
height:100px;
background-color:#FFFF66
}

.right {
float:left;
width:42%;
height:100px;
background-color:#FF9900;
}



#column4 {
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#66FFFF;
}

#column4 .box1, #column4 .box2, #column4 .box3, #column4 .box4{
float:left;
width:20.25%;
height:100px;
}

#column4 .box1 {
background-color: #FF3300;
margin-left:0;
}

.box2 {
background-color: #333399;
}

.box3 {
background-color: #3366FF;
}

.box4 {
background-color: #009900;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's a lot of extra div's just for safari... The gab is smaller indeed but still present and shifting. I'm using boxes with colored backgrounds so I need it to be pixelperfect :(